# How to get a char from mb_string through a for loop?

Tags: php, character-encoding, char

With this code:

```
$guessString = 'KUĆA';
$usedLetters = ['Ć'];
$userLetter = 'Ć';

for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($guessString); $i++) {
    $temp = $guessString[$i];
    if (in_array($guessString[$i], $usedLetters)) {
        echo $guessString[$i];
    } else {
        echo ' _ ';
    }
}
```

I am trying to compare if $userLetter (that is sent through GET link)
exists in $guessString.

But through debugging:

[image]

I finally see that it doesn't read the character right.

It gets `"?"` instead of `"Ć"`

So my question is: How to get the correct character with for loop ($guessString[$i])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with

```
$guessString[$i]
```

The indexing operator is not multibyte-aware, so it returns the `$i`th *byte* of the string. One way to fix this is using mb_substr:

```
$temp = mb_substr($guessString, $i, 1);
```

Of course, you should then use `$temp` everywhere you used `$guessString[$i]`.